# Estimates on norm Hessian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a twice differential function, with $\Omega$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose that we have the following:
$$D^2u\geq - \dfrac{(1+K^2)^{1/2}}{\epsilon}I$$

where the inequality is in the sense of quadratic form, so it means 
$$ 
D^2u+\dfrac{(1+K^2)^{1/2}}{\epsilon}I\text{ is positive semidefinite.}
$$

Now if $A$ is a matrix, let's define its norm of as
$$
|A|=\sqrt{\sum a_{ij}^2}.
$$
I want to show that $$\epsilon|D^2u|\geq 1.$$

**My attempts**:

- First, I thought I could considerate different definitions of the "norm" of a matrix, since all norms on the space of matrices are equivalent.
- Then I tried to use the fact that all the eigenvalues of $D^2u$ belong to the set $\big[-\epsilon^{-1}{(1+K^2)^{1/2}},+\infty\big)$.
- Last, I tried with fact that the sum of the elements of the Hessian is greater than $n{\epsilon^{-1}}{(1+K^2)^{1/2}}$.

Nothing useful arose.

Comment: $D^2u=0$ satisfies that inequality, and does not have norm greater than $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Anyway, once you fix that statement: for a symmetric matrix, $\rho(A) = \|A\| \leq |A|$, where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius (largest modulus of eigenvalue), $\|A\|$ is the Euclidean induced norm, and $|A|$ is the norm you defined (Frobenius norm). Hopefully this is enough to get what you need.